# Retrieve all lightning-datatable rows

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, visual-workflow, lightning-datatable, queryselector

How do I retrieve all lwc lightning datatable rows and not just the ones that are editable.

2 of my columns are non-editable (Section__c & Type__c) (coming from custom metadata) and 3 of my columns are editable (Findings, Comments, Location)

```
const COLS = [
{ label: 'Section', fieldName: 'Section__c' },
{ label: 'Type', fieldName: 'Type__c' },
{ label: 'Findings', fieldName: 'Findings', editable: true },
{ label: 'Location', fieldName: 'Location', editable: true },
{ label: 'Comments', fieldName: 'Comments', editable: true }];
```

I am using event.detail.draftValues to get the values but they return just the editable fields and only the rows which are edited. However, I need to access the values of entire datatable.   I tried this as well but row returns undefined and table data returns this
[image]

```
var table = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
var rows = table.data;
console.log('table data', table.data);
    rows.forEach(function(element){
    console.log('row ',  element.fieldName);
});
```

If Event.detail.draftValues returns the edited / changed values in the datatable and not data from Section__c and Type__c columns. In contrast, if I use data attribute then it returns only values from Section__c and Type__c columns.

Is there any way I can retrieve entire table data?

Answer (score 1):

The rows from draftValues will include the key field, which you can use to get the rest of the row:

```
draftValues.forEach((row) => {
  const record = this.data.find((data) => data.Id === row.Id);
  // Here, row is the edited data, record contains everything else
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did this and it did not log anything 
event.detail.draftValues.forEach((row) => {
            const record = this.data.find((data) => data.Id === row.Id);
            console.log('record ',record);
            // Here, row is the edited data, record contains everything else
        });

Comment: the code stops executing after const record assignment, @sfdcfox

Comment: This is the exact error
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
    at eval (https://gnbsocialdevelopment--devnp--c.visualforce.com/flow/modules/c/gNB_DataTable.js:4:2243)
    at c (https://gnbsocialdevelopment--devnp--c.visualforce.com/auraFW/javascript/QbIGjbUweWP5tLmFUE_dTw/aura_prod.js:100:82546)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.c (https://gnbsocialdevelopment--devnp--c.visualforce.com/auraFW/javascript/QbIGjbUweWP5tLmFUE_dTw/aura_prod.js:100:85924)

Comment: comments are not for extended discussions, if you are facing a new issue, please open a new post, and/or consider updating your original question. Thanks

Comment: @user138847 I have to run errands, but I'll write up some more when I get home

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks , really appreciate it

Comment: @user138847 Here's an example of merging the edits back with the original data: [webcomponent demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/KPKww9UwPW0DiLC6BS05/src/app.js?p=stories). Basically, we combine the original values with the edits. If you want, you can then use that merged data to perform further calculations.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks it worked